# Passing data from dropdown => to javascript function (Google App script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Hopefully I've included enough of the code w/o having to post it all...

I have a main function that calls displayDropdown()- which calls an HTMLService and displays a modal with a dropdown and a text box:
[image: screenshot of modal]
 .
This is the (condensed) javascript code that stores the data:

```html
<html>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="sendData()" />       
</html>
<script>
function sendData() {
          var values = {};
          values.textJob = document.getElementById("input").value;
          values.selectedJob = document.getElementById("dropJob").value;
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).grabData(values);
       };
        function closeIt(){
          google.script.host.close()
        };
</script>
```

Then the grabData() function in my .gs file:

```
function grabData(values) {
  if(values.textJob=="")
   //return values.selectedJob;
    Logger.log(values.selectedJob);
  else 
    //return values.textJob;
    Logger.log(values.textJob);
}
```

If I keep the returns commented out and try to log the data, I get the expected data logged. But if I reverse that, and return it instead, go back up to the main function just after displayDropdown() was called, and set a variable to equal the grabData function:

```
displayDropdown();
var stuff = grabData();
Logger.log(stuff);
```

I get an error that says:

[image: error message]

Why can't I access the data?

Comment: Are you sending any [restricted values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)?

Comment: The `return` just sends it back to the `.withSuccessHandler`.  If you want to send the data to another function then just add ` anotherfunction(values)` to your `grabData()` function.

Comment: Ok-- So how do I return the values I need in the grabData() function, to then be able to call that from another function?

Comment: Where is this other function? `Client or Server`

Comment: Both grabData() and the function that needs to call it are server-side .

Comment: Ok then as I've shown before just call that other function from within `grabData()`  Perhaps it would be helpful to show this other function in your question.

Comment: Oh I think I see what your problem is it's with displayDropdown right? `displayDropdown();
var stuff = grabData();
Logger.log(stuff);` `grabData()` can't go get the data from the client it can only receive it from the client so calling grabData() from another function doesn't do you any good.  You need to either save the data in Properties Service or call the other function from grabData while you have it.

Comment: Yes! that code is all in my "main" function. I want to assign a variable to grabData() to be able to use whatever is returned in there.

Comment: Okay then you need to save it in Properties Service while you have it in grabData so that you can use it in other functions later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200361/discussion-between-michael-m-and-cooper).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I usually do to send data from HTML form to GS:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="#" id="formID">
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector("#formID").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  var test = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler('client side function').processForm(this);
});
```

I usually pass 'this' as an argument and I process the information on the GS.

EDIT:

**GS**

```
function processForm(values){

  Logger.log(values);
  Logger.log(typeof values);

}
```

**Screenshoots**:

1- Web app

[image]

2- Server logs (function processForm)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Juan. Unfortunately that isn't working either.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are sending.  `Requests fail if you attempt to pass a Date, Function, DOM element besides a form, or other prohibited type, including prohibited types inside objects or arrays. Objects that create circular references will also fail, and undefined fields within arrays become null.`

Comment: @Cooper I'm sending an object of 2 strings. It's part of the sendData function that is shown underneath the main photo in the post.

Comment: @JuanBravoRoig Thanks again - What you provided me is basically what I have now. I'm able to send the form data to the GS function (If I LOG it). But I need to then assign that function to a variable, and call it from another function. That's where it fails .

Comment: That's not possible since you're expecting arguments which you're not providing! why do you want to call another function? you can do operations direclty inside the grabData function.